# Show right-aligned path in windows explorer taskbar icon (when hovering over it)?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, taskbar

For example, lets say I have the following open in multiple explorer tabs:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\bin\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\bin\conf
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\bin\include
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\bin\mods
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\bin\legal

When I hover over the windows explorer taskbar icon, it shows all the windows, but only the beginning  of the file path, "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18...", forcing me to hover over each one to find the one I am looking for:

[image]

Is there a way to show the path starting from the end (aka "right aligned")? I.e. I would rather see something like "...Java\jdk-18\bin". Or is there a way to show the full path? This way I don't have to hover over many (sometimes more than 10!) windows to find the one I am looking for.

Comment: Use details and you show see all. That is how I set up File Explorer Windows 10 and 11.

Comment: @John Sorry, what do you mean by "use details" and "show see all"?

Comment: File Explorer, View, and then select Details.  Then entire paths show up which should let you see that.  Superuser changed my attempt to write "should" to "show".   Use Details and you should see the path.

Comment: @John the file paths for each explorer window are still left-aligned and are still cut-off, such that I have to hover over each one to show the full path. To be clear I am not trying to see file paths within one folder --I typically have many different folders all open with e.g. my Documents folder being the root; i.e. they are cutoff like: "C:/Users/Ralph/Documents/..."

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but if you go to `View -> Options -> Change folder and search options -> View tab` and clear the checkbox for `Display the full path in the title bar`, you'll lose the full path, but the target folder name will be displayed.

Comment: @KeithMiller I may stick with this, thanks